# Как сделать цветокоррекцию с помощью кривых в android приложении?

Tags: java, android, opengl

Как сделать инструмент который берет фотографию и делает её цветокоррекцию?

Подобный инструмент реализован в Telegram, но посмотрев их исходный код совсем запутался т.к. еще новенький во всем этом

[image: пример инструмента из Telegram]

У меня получилось реализовать нечто подобное через OpenGL, но к сожалению мой метод оказался слишком ресурсозатратным и из-за этого просто лагает все

Может кто сталкивался с подобными задачами и может подсказать хотя бы направление куда двигаться или же ресурс где можно глянуть что-то подобное?

Comment: а вы свой openGL выполняете в отдельном потоке? Возможно ваше решение вполне подходящее, просто Main thread очень чувствителен к нагрузкам

Comment: Ну да,использую отдельный поток,просто в шейдере я использовал цикл на 300 проходов,из-за этого и лаги

Comment: "цикл на 300 проходов" - о боги .. ЗАЧЕМ?

Comment: Ну я не знал как реализовать по другому, просто одна из мыслей была